# DocumentsUI shows "Anonymous" application when requesting access to directory

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

One user reported that my app fails to request directory access when selecting a folder via the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent.
For some reason it does not show my application, instead "Anonymous":

[image]

Translated: "Allow Anonymous to access files in Camera. This will let Anonymous access current and future content stored in Camera".

The user has a MIUI 12 with Android 11 on a Mi Note 10 lite.
I have the same just with a Mi Note 10, no issues ofc.

Checked the Android source code:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DocumentsUI/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/documentsui/picker/ConfirmFragment.java#82

```
case TYPE_OEPN_TREE:
    final Uri treeUri = mTarget.getTreeDocumentUri();
    final BaseActivity activity = (BaseActivity) getActivity();
    final String target = activity.getCurrentTitle();
    final String text = getString(R.string.open_tree_dialog_title,
            **getCallingAppName**(getActivity()), target);
    message = getString(R.string.open_tree_dialog_message,
            **getCallingAppName**(getActivity()), target);

    builder.setTitle(text);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton(
            R.string.allow,
            (DialogInterface dialog, int id) -> {
                pickResult.increaseActionCount();
                mActions.finishPicking(treeUri);
            });
    break;


@NonNull
public static String getCallingAppName(Activity activity) {
    final String anonymous = activity.getString(R.string.anonymous_application);
    final String packageName = getCallingPackageName(activity);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(packageName)) {
        return anonymous;
    }

    final PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
    } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return anonymous;
    }

    CharSequence result = pm.getApplicationLabel(ai);
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(result) ? anonymous : result.toString();
}

public static String getCallingPackageName(Activity activity) {
    String callingPackage = activity.getCallingPackage();
    // System apps can set the calling package name using an extra.
    try {
        ApplicationInfo info =
                activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(callingPackage, 0);
        if (isSystemApp(info) || isUpdatedSystemApp(info)) {
            final String extra = activity.getIntent().getStringExtra(
                    Intent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME);
            if (extra != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(extra)) {
                callingPackage = extra;
            }
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // Couldn't lookup calling package info. This isn't really
        // gonna happen, given that we're getting the name of the
        // calling package from trusty old Activity.getCallingPackage.
        // For that reason, we ignore this exception.
    }
    return callingPackage;
}
```

...and it seems that for whatever reason my packagename isn't found. How can can happen?
Asked him to install one of my other apps, and it happens there as well.
Asked him then to install another app from the playstore (FX File Explorer) and there it does not happen.
So it is specific to his device and my app.

Comment: "Checked the Android source code" -- note that device manufacturers like Xiaomi frequently modify the OS source code. If we assume that this code is still accurate, my guess is that `getApplicationLabel()` is returning `null`. Do you have an `android:label` attribute in your `<application>` element in the manifest? If you do, then perhaps MIUI is doing something different there.

Comment: Sure, got the app:label there @CommonsWare also know that manufactures in general modify all kind of stuff in the source. That the dialog shows "Anonymous" is just one symptome, the worse one is that my app does not get read/write permission to the folder either. Since I got a pretty similar device Mi Note 10 (not lite) with the same MIUI version I would assume that the source code part is pretty much the same.

Comment: All I can suggest then is to install [this app](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.oF2pks.applicationsinfo/), look at FX File Explorer's manifest, and see what of relevance is different than yours.

Comment: `my app fails to request directory access when selecting a folder via the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE i` . Your app does not have to request anything if you use that action. Your app will be granted access to the directorie the user choosed. Please reformulate.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare ! app:description is not part of my application tag and some others regarding backups, don't see why one of those should cause it, but just for a test I added all of them and also removed the "&" from my app:label. Requested a logcat as well, maybe there is some info there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that this user having that issue turned off the MIUI Optimizations in the developer settings.[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Bug report: συσκευη, εκδοση miui, Play store install (alpha 1021). It was impossible to specify a b i o s file or specify a game image directory in when MIUI optimizations are off. Turning them back on fixed the issue and directories are scanned normally. Also on the popup to allow folder access the app displays as "Anonymous" instead of AetherSX2 on my system. Some developer was talking about having the same issue here.